# Can't understand ps | wc output differences

Tags: bash

I was trying to write a set of functions that could check to see if a process name was running when I encountered some unexpected output.  I've condensed the issue in the following script names isRunning.sh which depends on a system ps command that can take the '-fC' arguments...

```
#!/bin/bash
progname=isRunning.sh
ps -fC isRunning.sh
pRet=`ps -fC ${progname} | wc -l`
echo pRet $pRet
psOut=`ps -fC ${progname}` 
wcOut=`echo "${psOut}" | wc -l`
echo
echo ps output
echo "${psOut}"
echo
echo wcOut $wcOut
```

The first attempt at piping the ps output to wc gets a return of 3.  The second attempt gets the expected return value of 2.  Can anyone explain this behavior?  I figure it's got to be something stupid I am overlooking.

Thanks,
bbb

edit: my output

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      6717  5940  0 13:10 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./isRunning.sh
pRet 3

ps output
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      6717  5940  0 13:10 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./isRunning.sh

wcOut 2
```

Comment: show us the output of your program please.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to post formatted the way I want.

Comment: edit your question instead. comments are not for formatted text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get 2 both attempts. Your ps might be outputting an extra blank line, or somesuch, and then your shell's backtick expansion stripping it. Or maybe you actually had two processes matching the first time you ran it.

If you just want to see if its running, check the exit code from your ps:

```
if ps -C "${progname}" > /dev/null; then
  echo its running
else
  echo not running
fi
```

Even better, you should take a look at `pidof` and `pgrep` if you can rely on them being present on whichever systems you're targeting. Or use the LSB functions, if you're on Linux.

edit: Actually, since you're looking for copies of yourself running, you might be picking up the shell doing a fork to implement the pipe.

Comment: Thanks.  One of the things I needed to do was also check to see if there was an instance of the script already running.  So I was piping ps to wc to get the count.  I'll see if I can get pgrep to work.  I just don't understand what is happening in my script.  I can execute a ps -fC ${progname} | wc -l in my script before the pRet assignment and I get an output of 2.  I'm thinking something I'm doing is getting an extra line feed, just not sure where.  Maybe a redhat thing.

Comment: I just tried this script on a different redhat 9 machine an got the 3/2 results.  I can work around this with other options but I'm just curious.

Comment: @bittramp: May be a RedHat thing, I'm on Debian (or maybe its because I tested something slightly different—see my edit). But doesn't really matter, since RedHat surely has a `pidof`. Or you can just use the exit code.

Comment: I'm still floundering around with the controls here.  How do I see your edit?

Comment: You were correct with the fork theory.  I change the ps command I was getting a return of 3 and inserted a tee command and checked the output.  There were two processes.  Capturing the ps output into a variable then doing the fork was preventing this from showing up in the results.  Thanks